# Is virtual maas removed?

Tags: juju, maas

I am trying to browse in juju charm to locate vitual-maas charm and i couldn't find it ? Also no info and help link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtual-maas has never actually been submitted to the charm store for review as it was a bit of an experiment and not something I felt was of sufficient quality for general use; if you want to check it out:

```
 bzr branch lp:~virtual-maasers/charms/precise/virtual-maas/trunk
```